# Add event to visitor`s outlook calendar by visitor from website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, outlook-calendar

I am working on an educational platform. The platform contains study information for students. Student can see the deatils of their study plan by login into the site.

I want to add a feature into my website for the students that, when a student visits his/her study plans he/she can be able to add that information as an event into his/her microsoft outlook calendar (It can be a personal or work or school microsoft account) from the website by clicking a button. How can I achive this?

Please give me a guide line or any resources.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS Graph for getting the job done, see [Tutorial: Access Microsoft Graph from a secured JavaScript app as the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app-javascript?tabs=azure-powershell) for more information.